# c++ how to align output with for loop

Tags: c++, output

i am dealing with a school project and when i run the program,it needs to give a organized output .i tried to align it to the right side but it clearly didn't work as it can be seen. how can i reach the expected output?

code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        std::cout << i + 1 << "." << "\t" << std::setw(20) << std::right << "White Knight" << std::setw(30);

        if (i < 3) {
            std::cout << "W:" << 3 << " ";
            std::cout << "G:" << 4 << " ";
            std::cout << "B:" << 5 << " ";
            std::cout << "R:" << 6 << " ";
            std::cout << "L:" << 7 << " ";
            std::cout << "CMC:" << 8 << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "No Cost(Gives 1 G Mana)" << std::endl;
        }

        printf("\t");
        std::cout << std::setw(30) << "HP: " << 10 << " Attack Power:" << 30 << "   Ability: " << "First Strike";
        
    }
```

expected output:

```
          Card                           Mana Cost                          Card Info

1.        White Knight                   W:3 G:4 B:5 R:6 L:7 CMC:8          HP:10   Attack Power:20  Ability:First Strike 
2.        White Knight                   W:3 G:4 B:5 R:6 L:7 CMC:8          HP:10   Attack Power:20  Ability:First Strike 
3.        White Knight                   W:3 G:4 B:5 R:6 L:7 CMC:8          HP:10   Attack Power:20  Ability:First Strike 
4.        White Knight                   No Cost(Gives 1 G Mana)            HP:10   Attack Power:20  Ability:First Strike 
5.        White Knight                   No Cost(Gives 1 G Mana)            HP:10   Attack Power:20  Ability:First Strike
```

what i get:

```
1.              White Knight                            W:3 G:4 B:5 R:6 L:7 CMC:8
                                  HP: 10        Attack Power:30 Ability: First Strike2.         White Knight                            W:3 G:4 B:5 R:6 L:7 CMC:8
                                  HP: 10        Attack Power:30 Ability: First Strike3.         White Knight                            W:3 G:4 B:5 R:6 L:7 CMC:8
                                  HP: 10        Attack Power:30 Ability: First Strike4.         White Knight       No Cost(Gives 1 G Mana)
                                  HP: 10        Attack Power:30 Ability: First Strike5.         White Knight       No Cost(Gives 1 G Mana)
                                  HP: 10        Attack Power:30 Ability: First Strike
```

Comment: See `std::setw` and `std::justify` and `std::left`.

Comment: Looks like you just need to rethink where you've placed the `std::endl`s. `std::cout << "CMC:" << 8 << std::endl;` is going to be smack-dab in the middle of what you want to be a single line.

Comment: thanks i changed it but still doesn't look good.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that `printf` was designed for. You can print a string e.g. 10 characters wide padded by ' ' with "%10s". It's from C, but still extremely useful when formatting strings.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `std::setw(30)` is going to affect the `"W:"`, making its 2 characters take up 30 characters. I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out and compare it with your code. I've just added and removed few `endl`, added one `setw(36)` in `else` block and re-modified some space sequence

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    std::cout << i + 1 << "." << "\t" << std::setw(15) << std::right << "White Knight" << std::setw(15);

    if (i < 3) {
        std::cout << "W:" << 3 << " ";
        std::cout << "G:" << 4 << " ";
        std::cout << "B:" << 5 << " ";
        std::cout << "R:" << 6 << " ";
        std::cout << "L:" << 7 << " ";
        std::cout << "CMC:" << 8;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << setw(36) << "No Cost(Gives 1 G Mana)";
    }

    printf("\t");
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << "HP: " << 10 << " Attack Power:" << 30 << "   Ability: " << "First Strike" << endl;

}
```

**Output**

```
1.         White Knight             W:3 G:4 B:5 R:6 L:7 CMC:8         HP: 10 Attack Power:30   Ability: First Strike
2.         White Knight             W:3 G:4 B:5 R:6 L:7 CMC:8         HP: 10 Attack Power:30   Ability: First Strike
3.         White Knight             W:3 G:4 B:5 R:6 L:7 CMC:8         HP: 10 Attack Power:30   Ability: First Strike
4.         White Knight             No Cost(Gives 1 G Mana)           HP: 10 Attack Power:30   Ability: First Strike
5.         White Knight             No Cost(Gives 1 G Mana)           HP: 10 Attack Power:30   Ability: First Strike
```

Comment: Thank you very much. your code gives the output exactly as I asked.